# What is the true objective of panzadrome for the zx spectrum?

Tags: panzadrome

Can anyone tell me the objective of this game? I keep blowing tanks but I'm sure there is a main goal, they keep appearing without end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found out the objective behind it...

The eponymous Panzadrome is an island inhabited solely by robot
tanks of varying viciousness. You have been given the task of
destroying all the robots on the Panzadrome...

Each robot tank is remotely controlled from a central computer,
from which it gets its power. Plasma vents are a central part of
the power grid, and they have to be destroyed in order to knock
out both the computer and tanks. The computer is well aware of
this weakness, though, and wherever you find a vent there is also
a strong guardian force as well. Apart from the tanks you also
have to cope with heavily armed fun emplacements which fire on
any intruders.

Due to budget restrictions, you have been given a very
sub-standard tank with a one-shot turret and stone wheels!
Fortunately, factory depots are scattered around the island, each
specialising in a different type of tank component. You can visit
these factories and collect whatever system a factory makes.

Though the robot part stores are unaware that you are an
intruder, the computer's tanks will recognise you immediately and
try to destroy you.  Three weapons systems are available to you,
although at the start you only have the worst - a on-shot turret.
The others are mortars and mines, both of which must be collected
from the appropriate factory.

A Polycrete (TM) module is almost vital to have. Although you can
avoid the enemy tank fire if you are quick enough, their (and
your) exploding shells leave impassable craters in the ground.
This means that it can be quite easy to get stuck between a pair
of impassable craters. The solution is to use Polycrete (TM) -
press P to squirt it into the crater to fill the hole.

The Panzadrome itself is a 64-screen island, each screen flicking
to the next when the edge boundary is reached. A scanner helps
you navigate by highlighting the screen you are currently on. A
short-range scanner is also shown, displaying the tanks (which
you can see) and the mines (which you can't). As well as this,
the status screen shows the state of repair of any equipment you
may have; if something is too badly damaged you will lose it. You
only have one life, and if your shields run out a direct hit on
your tank will destroy it. Status bars depict shield level and
other counters show the amount of ammunition.

I'm getting back to this game, now that I know more about it :)

Alban

Answer (score 2):

The true objective of Panzadrome is to locate and destroy the flashing red and yellow checkerboard squares dotted around the island. The only way to destroy them is to us the mortar weapon as the targets are invariably located in areas where direct fire from your tank's cannon can't hit them. Although most of these squares are placed individually, there is a "Main reactor" complex located in the NE of the island from your starting location. It is heavily defended and can only be reached through a long and difficult route. Almost half the number of targets you need to destroy in order to complete the game are located in a cluster there. I usually leave this complex to the end after all other targets have been destroyed as the red tanks will be very aggressive in trying to defend it, giving you no respite wherever you go...[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, Rommel. Excellent first post!